# App freezen when I tried query.executeUpdate();

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I tried

```
TestDao.me().persistTest(main);
...
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO TD_TEST_MAIN(id,field1,field2,field3) VALUES(TD_TEST_MAIN_SEQ.NEXTVAL,:f1,:f2,:f3)")
                        .setParameter("f1", testMain.getField1())
                        .setParameter("f2", testMain.getField2())
                        .setParameter("f3", testMain.getField3());
                query.executeUpdate();
```

but after `executeUpdate` my app freezen. I have not error, and my app not work. But if I run this SQL in PLDeveloper it work fine.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO TD_TEST_MAIN(id,field1,field2,field3) VALUES('TD_TEST_MAIN_SEQ.NEXTVAL',:f1,:f2,:f3)")
```

I get grammar error

Comment: Does it actually work the first time and fail for subsequent calls?

Comment: Maybe you have a locked session somewhere?